# How to test if class works properly in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've written a class and want to test if it works well. For now I think the best way to do it is to create new console application referencing main project, then make new instance of my class and mess with it. This approach unlike others enables IntelliSense, using keywords (no full names for classes) and Debugging.

Anyone knows how to do it in more convenient way to do this without making new console app?

Comment: You should Google "unit testing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a console app to test your class is what I would call a ["poor man's unit test."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

*You are on the right track* in wanting to do this sort of testing and I (and most others on SO) would suggest using [a unit testing framework of some sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) to help you out. ([Mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) may be important and useful to you as well.)

Here's the thing though. Regardless of what framework you use, or if you go with a console app to test your code, you do have to create a separate project, or a separate, significant chunk of code of some sort, to be able to execute tests properly and independently. That's just part of the process. It is an investment but don't let the extra work keep you from doing it. It will save a lot time, and your skin, a little while in the future. Maybe even next week.

Also, while you're looking up unit testing make sure to also study up on [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (TDD.)

Comment: +1 for TDD.  I wasn't sure of its value until I tried it.  Now I can't imagine a more sensible way to work.

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing is absolutely the way to go.  Depending on what version of VS you are running, there may be unit testing functionality built in, or you may have to use an additional tool such as NUnit.  Both options are good and will allow you to fully test your classes.

Bear in mind also, that a comprehensive suite of unit tests will make refactoring much easier in the long run as well.  If you refactor and break your unit tests, you know you've made a boo-boo somewhere. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing is the way forward here> this is a good [introductory article](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/06/05/unit-testing-introduction/).

The basic concept of a unit test is that you isolate and invoke a specific portion of code and assert that the results are expected and within reason. For example lets say you have a simple method to return the square of a floating point number:

```
public float Square(float value)
{
    return value * value;
}
```

A reasonable unit test would be that the method returns the correct value, handles negetive values etc:

```
Assert.AreEqual(25, Square(5));
Assert.AreEqual(100, Square(-10));
```

Unit tests are also a good way to see how your code handles edge cases:

```
Assert.Throws<OverflowException>(Square(float.MaxValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS 2010, check out Pex and Moles...

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

Comment: +1 for mentioning pex & moles - although these tools might be a little advanced for someone who's completely new to unit testing

Answer (score 0):

The Console App approach is more of a test harness for your class, which is fine.

But you can also use a unit testing framework to test your class.  Visual Studio has one built in or you can leverage something like NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try the Object Test Bench in Visual Studio.  It should allow you to create a new instance, modify and view properties, and call some methods.  It usually only works with very simple apps, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio 2008 or higher you will be able to test your code using MSTest framework:

1.Open Test View window: Test/Windows/Test View;

2.Add new unit test project: right click on Solution in Solution Explorer/Add/New 
Project/Test Project;

3.Remove all files apart from UnitTest.cs file in created test project;

4.Write your unit test in method under [TestMethod] attribute:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var ranges = new Ranges();
        int sum = ranges.CountOccurrences(11);
        Assert.AreEqual(128, sum);
    }
}
```

5.Run your test from Test View window added in p.1

6.See test results in Test/Windows/Test Results window